# Active voice of "They expect to be invited"

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

> They expect to be invited

Here, this sentence is a passive voice. What is the active voice of it. If it haven't then give reasons please.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: It really is not a passive. Generally, passives with action verbs. Not stative (aka state aka static) verbs. http://www.grammaring.com/state-verbs-and-action-verbs That is a beginner's guide.

Comment: But @Lambie, both verbs here can be passivised: e.g. "that was not expected", "they were invited". The main verb here is active, but the verb in the infintive clause "invited" is passive.

Comment: The active voice of the infinitive clause should be "They expect someone to invite them"

Comment: Your sentence is called a 'short'' passive, i.e. one without an agent. There can be no active version unless a _by_ phrase is added, e.g. "They expect [to be invited by the mayor]" ~ "They expect [the mayor to invite them]". Note that only the bracketed subordinate clause can be passivised.

Comment: @user178049 Perhaps, but the overall sentence is not passive. [expect (meaning: assume is stative); it can also be active (meaning:waiting for someone/something)] and the passive infinitive after the stative verb is a secondary issue. Here, it is stative followed by a to infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you give *is* in the active voice.

The passive version of the sentence could be something like:

> An invitation is expected.

---

If you're actually talking about the passive infinitive of *to be invited* then a similar change could be made to the original sentence:

> They expect an invitation.

Or, to assume more about the context and keep the second verb:

> They expect their friends will invite them.

Comment: The main verb is active, but contains a passive infinitive. OP may be thinking of how does one turn that infinitive into an active sentence

Comment: @eques Noted. It's not clear from the question if that's the issue (I hadn't assumed so). But I've updated my answer.

Comment: The OP's example is a 'short'' passive, i.e. one without an agent. Adding a  _by_ phrase gives, for example "They expect [to be invited by the mayor]" which does of course have the active ~ "They expect [the mayor to invite them]". Note that only the bracketed subordinate clause can be passivised in this instance.